# Looping through df dictionary in order to merge df's in Pandas

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dictionary with dataframes

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]], columns=['A', 'B'], index = [1, 2, 3])
B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], columns=['A', 'B'], index = [1, 2, 3])
C = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]], columns=['A', 'B'], index = [1, 2, 3])

df_all = {'df1': A, 'df2': B, 'df3': C}
```

I would like to merge them 'inner' by their indexes but with iteration using a for loop. It would have to be the equivalent of doing

```
df4 = pd.merge(A, B, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
df5 = pd.merge(df4, C, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

And the result would look like

```
   A_x  B_x  A_y  B_y  A  B
1    2    1    1    1  1  2
2    2    1    2    2  1  2
3    2    1    3    3  1  2
```

I tried something silly like

```
for key, value in df_all.iteritems():
    df = pd.merge(value, value, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

But this gives me a nonsense result.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Try `pd.merge(A, A, ...)` and you'll see why your results don't work.

Comment: @chrisaycock I know why they don't work. The problem is I don't know how to make them work. Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import functools

A = pd.DataFrame([[2, 1], [2, 1], [2, 1]], columns=['A', 'B'], index = [1, 2, 3])
B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], columns=['A', 'B'], index = [1, 2, 3])
C = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]], columns=['A', 'B'], index = [1, 2, 3])

df_all = {'df1': A, 'df2': B, 'df3': C}
merge = functools.partial(pd.merge, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
df = functools.reduce(merge, df_all.values())
print(df)
```

yields

```
   A_x  B_x  A_y  B_y  A  B
1    2    1    1    2  1  1
2    2    1    1    2  2  2
3    2    1    1    2  3  3
```

Note that `df_all.values()` returns the values in the `dict` in an unspecified order. If you want a particular order, you'll have to do something like sort by the keys...

---

Or, you could create a DataFrame with hierarchical columns using `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(df_all, axis=1).dropna(axis=0)
print(df)
```

yields

```
   df1     df2     df3   
     A  B    A  B    A  B
1    2  1    1  1    1  2
2    2  1    2  2    1  2
3    2  1    3  3    1  2
```

(Caveat: Using `pd.concat` is fragile here -- I'm assuming the DataFrames do not have NaN values, but may have different indexes. The `dropna` is then used to produce an inner join.)

Comment: the df have different indexes. The concat option is a nice alternative. Thanks

Comment: Sure `df_all.values()` is a list (or iterable), so you can supply a different list here if you wish.

Comment: Last question. is it possible to transform the hierarchical df to a normal df....like get rid of the extra level with df1..df2 ?

Comment: Dumb question. For information purposes the answer is    df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)

Comment: Another alternative is to use `df = pd.concat(df_all.values(), axis=1).dropna(axis=0)`. (So the hierarchical column is not created in the first place.)

Comment: Or to drop a level, `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)`.

Comment: I was sure there was some kind of arg for this operation.

Comment: ah yes, is "keys" in concat!

Answer (score 2):

concat has you covered:

```
In [11]: pd.concat([A, B, C], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])
Out[11]:
   df1     df2     df3
     A  B    A  B    A  B
1    2  1    1  1    1  2
2    2  1    2  2    1  2
3    2  1    3  3    1  2
```